# Generating Unique sequence number in mule

Tags: java, mule, sequence

I have a requirement in my project.
I want to generate an increasing unique sequence number which will be mapped to a specific field(interchange id ) for the output xml file.
The customer wants to generate some alert around this number. So they are very specific about the number should be
1. Unique 2. Increasing.

So now I have two approach to this case

1. I will generate a sequence with the help of oracle sequence. But the problem is again they do not want to unnecessarily hit the database.
2. Will genearate in java with the help of static variable. But I feel its not full proof. I think if my application or server restarts then the static variable will start form 0 again. In that case the number will not be unique.

So my question is, if we can get this something easily in mulesoft or any idea is apreciated

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Use the static field, but grab the value from the database. Given that there's no requirement that the numbers need to be consecutive, you can increment the database value by f.e. 100 each time, then you need to hit the database only every 100th number that you need to produce.

Answer (score 0):

Obtaining a sequence value from the database does not qualify as "hitting the database *unnecessarily*".

It **is** *necessary* in order to obtain a unique sequence value in an efficient and scalable way.

While sequence contention isn't unheard of in an Oracle database it is usually not the biggest problem you have in a busy database. And one of the easiest things to fix: increase the sequence *cache*.

---

If you do know (as opposed to just assuming) that you **will** get a performance problem, then you *might* think about increasing the sequence *increment* to a very high number. Then, when you start your application you call `nextval` and get the upper limit of numbers you can hand out inside your Java code without risking anything. If you reach that limit, call `nextval` again to get the next slice of numbers. Essentially combining your static variable with the sequence persistence that Oracle offers

But again: I doubt that calling the sequence for *each* number will get you into trouble any time soon (and if it does, you probably will have other performance problems that are far bigger)

Answer (score 0):

Another point as to why it is preferable to use something like the database for this is because a static variable will only work while you have a single JVM instance.

If you ever need to scale through more nodes this becomes a very brittle pattern (unless you are able to avoid by using GUID's instead - but this won't fulfil your incrementing requirement in this case).

Instead of 'the' database you could use another efficient mechanism like memcache or Redis?